# How to show list of all committed files till last commit in a git repository?

Tags: git, github

I know if I want to get the list of all committed files in a particular commit if I know the commit hash or relative position from HEAD I can get the list of files using

```
git show --stat <commit-id> --names-only
```

or

```
git show --stat HEAD~n --names-only
```

but if I want to get list of all the files that have been committed till now since the first commit, how can I get them.

One possible way I can think of is to write a bash script ( or bash command) to loop over all the commits and run above command but I wanted to ask if there is any *git way* to achieve this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get list of all the files that have been committed till now since the first commit

You could do a [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---name-only) between:

- [the empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766506/6309) 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
- a given commit SHA1

That is:

```
git diff --name-only 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 <SHA1>
```

Comment: It works indeed. Thanks to you that I added this `the empty tree` thing to my knowledge. I was never aware of it.

Comment: @CodeTalker Yes, the empty tree is neat, and will soon evolve when Git will use SHA2 (it will be `6ef19b41225c5369f1c104d45d8d85efa9b057b53b14b4b9b939dd74decc5321`)

Comment: yes, I saw your post on the link provided above under `the empty tree` regarding SHA2. Also, apart from it, I am amazed to look at your profile, you are one of the giant knowledge base on Stackoverflow. I am happy to found you today. I am gonna follow you to gain more knowledge from you :)

Comment: @CodeTalker I post mainly on Git these days, and the others contributors (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/topusers) are generally way better than me, starting with torek (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) who, incidentally, asked about the empty tree back in 2012.